# Assembly MIPS: Reverse Printing a string

Tags: assembly, mips

Let's say we type the word "test" and we want the programme to return as output this word reversed ("tset").

With C, a typical for loop can easily make this work.

```
for(i='/0'; i>=0; i--)
printf("%c", str[i]);
```

But at MIPS, things get pretty messy at least.

At tried to make it work by making two loops. One for simply reading each character of the string and another for reverse-printing them:

```
.data
str: .space 15

.text
.globl main
main:

li  $v0, 8  #scan a string
la  $a0, str
la  $a1, 15
syscall

add $t0, $zero, $zero   #counter

readingloop:

        lb  $a0, str($t0)   #read each character

        beq $a0, '\0', readingexit  #make sure the string is not yet over

        addiu   $t0, $t0, 1     #i++

j readingloop
readingexit:


reversingloop:
        li  $v0, 11     #print a character you have read    
        lb  $a0, str($t0)   
        syscall

        beq $a0, '0', reversingexit #make sure the string 
                                       #hasn't reached the first letter yet
        subiu   $t0, $t0, 1     #i--

j reversingloop
reversingexit:

li  $v0, 10
syscall
```

And it works kinda fine.

Kinda. Because at MARS, the cursor just keeps on running towards right.

[image]

It seems like the reversing loop needs to check when the counter succeeds the zero at the "i>=0" thing of the for loop we said above.

How can this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems:

- `reversingloop` should pre-decrement `$t0` (i.e. do the `subiu   $t0, $t0, 1` *before* the `lb`, not after), otherwise you start by reading the NUL-terminator that you found in `readingloop`.
- The exit condition for `reversingloop` should not be that you've found a NUL-terminator, because the NUL-terminator is located at the *end* of the string, and you're iterating towards the *beginning* of the string (btw, you've mistyped `'\0'` as `'0'` in one place). The exit condition should be that `$t0` equals 0.

Comment: The first point is right, I should've known better. The second one though seems a bit odd to me, since it's working by retyping '\0' to my mistake. How can i make the exit condition be true when $t0 == str? I don't know if "branch if equal" faction receives the "str" variable.

Comment: See my edit. I forgot that `$t0` contained an offset, not the full address. So you should be exiting when `$t0` equals 0 (not when `$a0` equals 0 which you're doing now). You might say that it's "working", but take a look at the value of `$t0` when the program finishes and you should see that you've been reading outside the bounds of the array.